# How to share a variable between two classes?

Tags: c#

How would you share the same object between two other objects? For instance, I'd like something in that flavor:

```
class A
{
   private string foo_; // It could be any other class/struct too (Vector3, Matrix...)

   public A (string shared)
   {
       this.foo_ = shared;
   }

   public void Bar()
   {
       this.foo_ = "changed";
   }
}

...
// inside main
string str = "test";
A a = new A(str);

Console.WriteLine(str); // "test"
a.Bar();
Console.WriteLine(str); // I get "test" instead of "changed"... :(
```

Here, I don't want to give a ref to the Bar method. What I want to achieve is something that would look like that in C++:

```
class A
{
  int* i;
public:
  A(int* val);
};

A::A (int* val)
{
  this->i = val;
}
```

I read there is some ref/out stuff, but I couldn't get what I'm asking here. I could only apply some changes in the methods scope where I was using ref/out arguments...
I also read we could use pointers, but is there no other way to do it?

Comment: In your example specifically, strings are not a good example since they are immutable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sharing objects. You passed a reference to a string into the A constructor. That reference was copied into the private member `foo_`. Later, you called `B()`, which changed `foo_` to "changed".

At no time did you modify `str`. `str` is a local variable in `main`. You never passed a reference to it.

If you had wanted to change `str`, you could have defined B as

```
   public void Bar(ref string s)
   {
     this.foo_ = "changed";
     s = this.foo_;
   }
```

---

Consider:

```
public class C
{
    public int Property {get;set;}
}

public class A
{
    private C _c;
    public A(C c){_c = c;}

    public void ChangeC(int n) {_c.Property = n;}
}

public class B
{
    private C _c;
    public B(C c){_c = c;}

    public void ChangeC(int n) {_c.Property = n;}
}
```

in main:

```
C myC = new C() {Property = 1;}
A myA = new A(myC);
B myB = new B(myC);

int i1 = myC.Property; // 1
myA.ChangeC(2);
int i2 = myC.Property; // 2
myB.ChangeC(3);
int i3 = myC.Property; // 3
```

Comment: Indeed it would cope here to do it like how you suggest, but it is not what I want to do. Here, I really want my class A and B to work on the same object by giving it to the A and B constructor. Then they would work by themselves on the shared object without having to have a ref argument at each method call (I want to keep my Bar method without arguments). 
eg: an Oriented Bounding Box which follows its object. If I can share the position between OBB and the object, I would not have to update the OBB position each time the object moves.

Comment: Then just pass the object to both constructors. That's not what you did in your example. Also, passing a string won't work, as strings are immutable.

Comment: ok I get it for classes. But if C is a struct, this code doesn't work anymore... How would you fix that ? (for instance, it would be to pass Vector3 which are struct...)

Comment: @Altefquatre: you're right about that. It doesn't actually make sense to share an instanfe of a value type. How would you share the number 1?

Comment: Yes indeed it doesn't make sense to share a number value, but it does if you want to share a variable holding this value. I guess that's why people is suggesting to do a wrapper, and that's what I'm heading for, even if I would have preferred a more convenient way (creating a class for each struct is quite a pain...). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Altefquatre: create a generic wrapper.

Comment: @John: it's not a bad idea at all xD

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your string inside a class. You need to do this because strings are immutable. Any attempt to change a string actually results in a new string.

```
class Foo {
    class StringHolder {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    private StringHolder holder = new StringHolder();
    public string Value  {
       get { return holder.Value; }
       set { holder.Value = value; }
    }
    public Foo() { }
    // this constructor creates a "linked" Foo
    public Foo(Foo other) { this.holder = other.holder; } 
}

// .. later ...

Foo a = new Foo { Value = "moose" };
Foo b = new Foo(a); // link b to a
b.Value = "elk"; 
// now a.Value also == "elk"
a.Value = "deer";
// now b.Value also == "deer"
```

Comment: +1 I would probably make `StringHolder` a private nested class though.

Answer (score 2):

I would split my answer to 2 parts:
1) If the variable is a reference type than it is already shared since you pass its reference to all interested objects. The only thing you should pay attention is that the reference type instances are mutable.
2) If the variable is a value type than you would have to use ref or out or some wrapper that is mutable and you can change the value inside the wrapper using a method or a property.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the paramter as a reference to your method,

```
    class A
        {
            private string foo_; // It could be any other class/struct too (Vector3, Matrix...) 

            public A(string shared)
            {
                this.foo_ = shared;
            }

            public void Bar(ref string myString)
            {
               myString = "changed";
            }
        }

static void Main()
        {
            string str = "test";
            A a = new A(str);

            Console.WriteLine(str); // "test" 
            a.Bar(ref str);
            Console.WriteLine(str);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is a string, it is a reference.
Try to clone the string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.clone.aspx